# Cypress.io on Apple Silicon M1 with Yarn – "Cypress failed to start. This may be due to a missing library or dependency."

Tags: laravel, cypress, yarnpkg

I try to use Cypress for tests. With Laravel and Yarn as a package (v8.3.1) on MacBook with Apple M1 chip. Installation was ok, but all I can see after `cypress open` is:

```
Cypress failed to start.

This may be due to a missing library or dependency. https://on.cypress.io/required-dependencies

Please refer to the error below for more details.
----------
rosetta error: /var/db/oah/c642c6...79172/Cypress.aot: attachment of code signature supplement failed: 1
----------
Platform: darwin (20.5.0)
Cypress Version: 8.3.1
```

How I should run Cypress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution. All what you have to do is to upgrade your Mac with M1 chip to OS ver. 11.5.x (BigSur)

Cypress with BigSur 11.5.x works fine.

Answer (score 2):

After the installation, don't forget to install the Rosetta as well!

`softwareupdate --install-rosetta --agree-to-license`

reference:
https://www.cypress.io/blog/2021/01/20/running-cypress-on-the-apple-m1-silicon-arm-architecture-using-rosetta-2/

Answer (score 1):

You can try installing it with the  `--force` flag

```js
npx cypress install --force
```

Comment: I used force flag for reinstall, but same error when I want to open cypress

Answer (score 0):

This could be because the install process was interupted, run this to restart the dependency install (from the project folder)

```js
.\node_modules\.bin\cypress.cmd install
```

Comment: Tried to install one more time – same error unfortunately

Comment: You may have some luck with `cypress cache clear` to remove the binaries. Also, try again in another folder.

Comment: Tried to clean cache before. I think, maybe docker is an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue on my Mac (2019, 16 inch MacBook Pro) by navigating to my git repo with my Cypress project and doing the following commands, one-by-one:

```
npm i
./node_modules/.bin/cypress install --force
```

The `./node_modules/.bin/cypress install --force` line was the key! After that everything worked properly for me.